# If a property holds for arbitrary compact set in a metric space, does it also holds for the metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Suppose a metric space $(X, d).$ Further suppose that a property $A$ holds for arbitrary compact subset of $X.$ Does the property $A$ also hold for $X$?

#### Context

I hoped for some general theorems of the above kind. I am not expert in mathematical analysis so I hoped that there exists a class of properties that also hold for the space when they hold for its compact subsets.

Comment: Is $X$ compact?

Comment: well, it depends on the property. If $A$ is compactness itself, the answer is no, for example.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 It need not to be compact. I am more interested in non-compact $X.$ E.g. $X$ is Euclidean space.

Comment: @ush Good answer! (Or bad question..) Thank you! Is there another example? If $X$ is metric space, $f$ is continuous function on arbitrary compact subset of $X$. Is $f$ also continuous on $X$?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer do you expect. If $X$ is not compact, it depends entirely on $X$ and property. Are you asking for a kind of a list of what properties hold, and which don't?

Comment: @user2194122 No, take for example $X=[0,1]$, $A_0=\{0\}$, $A_i=[1/(i+1), 1/i]$ and $f(0)=1$, $f(x)=0$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @Marcin Łoś I hoped for some general theorems. I am not expert in mathematical analysis so I hoped that there exists a class of properties that also hold for the space.

Comment: I see. I think it would be a good idea to reword a question a bit to make it clear that this is what you're asking for (at least for me a question is a bit confusing as it stands).

Comment: You might be interested in $\sigma$-finiteness: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure Often a statement is proved for a finite measure space and then extended to the $\sigma$-finite case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is a compact metric space, then $X$ itself is a compact subset of $X$, so the property $A$ must hold for $X$.

If $X$ is not compact, then let $A$ be the property that a subset of $X$ is compact. Then $A$ holds for any compact subset of $X$, but $A$ does not hold for $X$ itself.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. If $X$ is not compact does there exist a general class of properties (e.g. about functions - convergence, continuity, ...) that hold for $X$ itself?

Comment: @user2194122 It is more common to make transition from local to global, where *local* means "every point has a neighborhood in which $A$ holds". Then there is a bunch of such properties: continuity, differentiability, etc. In a locally compact space, where we have compact neighborhoods of points, this also yields examples of the kind you asked. When a space is not locally compact (like infinite-dimensional normed space), this usually means its compact subsets are very small and do not give the right idea of how the whole space behaves.

Answer (score 0):

No; there are , e.g., fixed point theorems that hold for compact subspaces, but not for the whole space. Or, you may have subspaces, like $\mathbb Q$ of the Reals that are not complete under the standard Euclidean metric, but the Reals themselves are complete.